# Application Version Number Upgrade Indicator

Tags: flutter, versioning, mobile-development

What I want to ask is simple, but I'm not sure if there is a **general rule** that applies to this.

So for example I have an application whose current version is `1.1.1`.
So, when should I upgrade to `1.1.2`?
When should I upgrade to `1.2.1`?
When should I upgrade to `2.1.1`?

At that time I briefly read an article about the indicator for when you should increase it to `1.1.2`, that was because of a small change, `1.2.1` because of a moderate change and so on.
But I forgot the explanation and where to find it...

Can anyone explain it, or find a reference?
Thank You

Comment: https://semver.org

Comment: You wouldn’t upgrade from 1.1.1 to 1.2.1 but to 1.2.0. Nor from 1.1.1 to 2.1.1 but to 2.0.0.

Comment: @Biffen It's just an example.. Thanks for the reference link